# Install.packages installs source in Rstudio console but binary when using Rscript

Tags: r, rscript, install.packages

I am working on a package that supports interaction with an alternatively shaped library structure which supports installing multiple versions of a package in parallel (RVClibrary, soon on CRAN). Recently, I met some strange behaviour and I hope someone can explain.

When installing a package, it can sometimes have a *source* version which is later than the *binary* version. The source (uncompiled C code) is in that case not yet compiled (by ...?) but contains a later version than the already compiled binary version. The following is shown in my case:

```
  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rlang  0.2.0  0.3.4              TRUE
```

A choice is given to the user whether A or B should be relatively installed or compiled. In other words, if you want version 0.2.0 or 0.3.4 (for which you need Rtools).

This choice will not be given when the `install.packages.compile.from.source` option is set.

```
> options(install.packages.compile.from.source = "always")
> install.packages('rlang', lib = "C:\\test", quiet = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rlang  0.2.0  0.3.4              TRUE

installing the source package ‘rlang’
```

The **source** is installed.

But when I create a simple script (I name it *`install_test.R`*):

```
packageName <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]

cat(packageName, '\n')

options(install.packages.compile.from.source = "always")
install.packages(packageName, lib = "C:\\test", quiet = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

The following behaves the same with system in R and directly in CMD.
*(Make sure you have the path to `Rscript.exe` in your environment variable PATH)*

```
> system("Rscript.exe C:\\test\\install_test.R rlang")
rlang 

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rlang  0.2.0  0.3.4              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

The **Binaries** are installed!

**I need to be able to always install the Source version** so I do not run into dependency issues. ggplot2 for example depends on `>= 0.2.1` already...

### Summary

- I have Rtools 3.5 installed (which devtools can find using both routes and thinks it is not compatible..., but installing from source works fine in Rstudio, and (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) CRAN says it's compatible to)
- R version:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
year           2016
month          06
day            21
svn rev        70800
language       R
version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair
```

- running Windows 10
- The difference between environment variables can be seen here (Rstudio to the right, Rscript left): https://pasteboard.co/IasIVMe.png

---

(my edit here is removed to keep it clean. See my answer (or history) to read more)

Comment: Are you required for some reason to run such an old version of R, or could you possibly upgrade?

Comment: What does `Sys.which(Sys.getenv("MAKE", "make"))` return? If R can't find `make`, then it will override that option to "never'

Comment: Thanks you both for your quick reply! @joran, I would like to provide a method that is not R version (bug release) sensitive, and otherwise I want to know precisely what the issue is and what version  is required. I am running this R version to keep delivering comparable results, other people might have similar motivations.

Comment: @MrFlick, that's very interesting, I will try that. I would be so frustrated if it is again an "I can't find Rtools" problem that is poorly reported back...

Comment: @MrFlick, I found the [underlying code](https://8nhzfyyq66.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/lambdar?e=install.packages) for install.packages, and can confirm what you say. I thought Rtools (as the installer suggests) could be found by letting the installer edit the registry alone. Must I have PATHS specified? `Sys.which(Sys.getenv("MAKE", "make"))` returns nothing, but also nothing in the Rscript. So `make.exe` cannot be found, but Rstudio does manage to build from source... I will update my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried different environment variable configurations to see if **installing/compiling from source** can be performed **by an Rscript.exe** instance running `install.packages`.

(It works differently (less restrictive) when working from Rstudio console. It seems that it recognizes the *registry entry*. It works without specifying an environment var at all).

1. Set `MAKE` variable (`Sys.setenv(MAKE = 'C:\\Rtools\\bin\\make.exe')`) (partially SUCCEEDS)
2. Set `PATH` variable (appending to the beginning)

   - Include all Rtools bin dirs (`C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\Rtools\\mingw_32;C:\\Rtools\\mingw_64`) (SUCCEEDS)
   - Include Rtools `C:\\Rtools\\bin` only (SUCCEEDS)
   - Include Rtools `C:\\Rtools\\bin` only (to the end of PATH variable) (SUCCEEDS)
   - Include Rtools `C:\\Rtools\\mingw_32` only (FAILS)
   - Include Rtools `C:\\Rtools\\mingw_64` only (FAILS)
3. Set only the `PATH` and not the `MAKE` variable.

Under the condition that the following property is set: `options(install.packages.compile.from.source = "always")`

Solution 1:
The [`install.packages`](https://8nhzfyyq66.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/lambdar?e=install.packages) function 'checks' if it should try building from source by looking for the 'MAKE' environment variable `nzchar(Sys.which(Sys.getenv("MAKE", "make")))`. Unfortunately, if you only specify the MAKE environment variable, which you must provide a complete path to make it (the `Sys.which`) work, it will still not find all required source build tools (Rtools/bin) that appear to be necessary and crash without any clarrification:

```
> Sys.setenv(MAKE = 'C:\\Rtools\\bin\\make.exe')
> system("Rscript.exe C:\\R_projecten\\test\\install_test.R rlang")

     There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
   rlang  0.2.0  0.3.4              TRUE

   installing the *source* package 'rlang'

   Warning messages:
   1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\R_projecten\test\test4" C:\Users\SB947~1.FRO\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbEcl6/downloaded_packages/rlang_0.3.4.tar.gz' had status 1 
   2: In install.packages(packageName, lib = "C:\\R_projecten\\test\\test4",  :
     installation of package 'rlang' had non-zero exit status
```

So solution 1 is not sufficient, and can even be replaced by solution 3:

```
   PATH : C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\x64; ....  ;C:\Rtools\bin; 
   MAKE : 

     There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
   rlang  0.2.0  0.3.4              TRUE

   installing the source package 'rlang'
```

As shown, **only providing `C:/Rtools/bin` in PATH, and no MAKE variable is sufficient**.

The check decribed earlier checks if the MAKE variable exists, and use that value, or it will look for `make`, the program name (provided as default to `Sys.getenv`). When specifying the PATH only, the `make(.exe)` file can be found and no MAKE env var is required. With the added benefit of already pointing to the Rtools/bin directory from which apparently more files are needed.

Which files I am still wondering though...

NOTE: The check `nzchar(Sys.which(Sys.getenv("MAKE", "make")))` is NOT sufficient to prove that your environment is ready for building from source.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set the environment variable at all. `Sys.getenv("MAKE", "make")` will just return "make" when the variable isn't get which is what you want most of the time. You would just need to change this if you changed the name of your make executable for some reason. It doesn't need the full path to your executable. The `Sys.which()` part does check that it can find an executable version of the program in your PATH so it can actually run the application. But this shouldn't have anything to do with the registry.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, I hope you understood my good intention. In the last sentence, I was just trying to say that more checks than only 'if make(.exe) can be found' are necessary to find out if you are ready to compile from source without problems.